# Converting String into Bitmap

Tags: android, string, bitmap, arrays

I'm trying to convert `String` into `Bitmap` object to put it then on `ImageView`. `String` value is downloaded from web and is not null. Actually it is a jpeg file which I can download and open via browser.

I tried to use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` method  but got `--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` message.

```
try{
      byte[] encodeByte = encodedString.getBytes();
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
      return bitmap;
    } catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
 }
```

`encodedString` is actually a string I downloaded before:

```
...
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
String encodedString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
...
```

Comment: Try with the same string stored locally, first

Comment: @Alex do you mean to write a string into the file and then read it?

Comment: @Alex I tried to write the string into internal storage and read it then but the result is same (not surprise honestly)..Could you clarify what do you mean under locally stored string?

Comment: could you give any string example?

Comment: @deadfish http://txs.io/B3qb

Comment: @deadfish this image is valid because I get jpg when I download from browser. The issue is to do it programmatically

Comment: string you gave me is not valid, it should be data without new lines. Can you share working link?

Comment: When you convert binary data to a string, it changes the data (to valid characgers, goes through encoding).

Comment: @yoah I don't convert binary to string, I convert string to binary. `encodedString.getBytes();`

Comment: When you call EntityUtils.toString(resEntity), you convert binary to string

Comment: @yoah yes, you was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, when converting binary data to a string, it changes the data (to valid characgers, goes through encoding) at `EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)`

Thanks to @yoah

Changed code to

```
byte[] img = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resEntity);
```

and then passed this byte array into BitmapFactory

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
```

Image displays correctly.

So, the conclusion is that is better to operate with byte array than with accessory String.